# Begriff für die Gesamtheit aller Zustände und Prozesse im Gehirn

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es einen Begriff für die Gesamtheit aller Zustände und Prozesse des Gehirns? [Denken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/denken), Bewusstsein, [Geist](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Geist) usw. bezeichnen jeweils nur den bewussten Teil dessen, was im Gehirn "vor sich geht", daneben gibt es jedoch auch unbewusste Inhalte und Prozesse.

---

Es ist schwierig, diese Frage unmissverständlich zu formulieren. Zuerst hatte ich nach der "Gesamtheit aller mentalen Zustände und Prozesse" gefragt, aber @adjan hat mich richtigerweise darauf hingewiesen, dass "mental" eben gerade nur die bewussten Kongnitionen meint. Nun habe ich das "mentale" aus meiner Frage gelöscht und muss erkennen, dass sie dadurch in die andere Richtung missverständlich wird, weil sie nun nach der physiologischen Hirnaktivität zu fragen scheint.

Ich möchte deshalb klar stellen, dass ich nach den *Inhalten* frage, aber eben nicht nur den bewussten, sondern auch den nicht bewussten (Intuition) bzw. nicht rationalen, wie z.B. prozedural Gelerntem (Bewegungsabläufe), Einstellungen (Fremdenfeindlichkeit), "Geschmack" (mir schmeckt Spinat nicht), Persönlichkeit (Extroversion) und ähnlichem.

Ich denke, dass "Psyche" dieser Vorstellung am nächsten kommt, auch wenn der Begriff "Psyche" auf vielerlei unterschiedliche Weise verwendet wird und nicht nur diese sondern auch teils widersprechende Bedeutungen hat.

Comment: Was ist denn mit einem so platten Begriff wie *Gehirntätigkeit* oder *Gehirnaktivität*?

Comment: "Gehirnaktivität" bezeichnet nur die phyisologische Ebene (Durchblutung, elektrische Aktivität usw.). Diese machen zwar auch die Inhalte aus, diese sind durch den Begriff aber nicht mitgemeint. Wenn man den Begriff googelt, findet man immer Texte zu Kernspintomografie und ähnlichem. "Gehirntätigkeit" meint, so wie ich den Begriff verstehe, wie tätig das Gehirn gerade ist, also das Ausmaß der physiologischen Aktivität, oder ist einfach ein Synonym zu "Gehirnaktivität".

Comment: Ist das so? Dann ist *Denken* keine Gehirnaktivität?

Comment: So, wie ich die Google-Funde verstehe, nicht.

Comment: Ist es nicht etwa so, dass die meisten Google-Funde das tatsächlich wissenschaftlich mess- und technisch Erfassbare wiedergeben dürften? Und du deshalb so viel "Elektrik" findest? Ich wäre mit solchen Schlüssen aus Google-Suchergebnissen vorsichtig. *Denken* nicht als Gehirnaktivität zu werten, finde ich ein bißchen *hirnrissig*.

Comment: Darin drückt sich die Trennung akademischer Disziplinen aus. Die Medizin und Physiologie, die sich mit den Organen und deren Funktion beschäftigen, sprechen von Hirntätigkeit, -aktivität und -funtionen, die Psychologie dagegen spricht von Psyche, Gefühlen, Kognitionen usw. Die Psychologie verwendet die physiologischen Begriffe nur interdisziplinär (in der Neuropsychologie), wenn sie mit physiologischen Messungen den Denkinhalten auf die Spur kommen will. Das nennt man dann neurophysiologische Korrelate von Kognition: https://www.google.de/search?q=neurophysiologische+Korrelate+von+Kognition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich denke, *Psyche* ist der Begriff, den du suchst.

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Psyche_Seele_Gemuet_Innenleben):

> 1. (bildungssprachlich, Fachsprache) Gesamtheit des menschlichen Fühlens, Empfindens und Denkens; Seele

[The Free Dictionary:](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/Psyche)

> im heutigen Sprachgebrauch: die Gesamtheit bewusster und unbewusster Vorgänge sowie die geistigen und intellektuellen Funktionen

[Dorsch](https://portal.hogrefe.com/dorsch/psyche/):

> In der Ps[ychologie] steht P[syche] für die Gesamtheit Bewusstes/Unbewusstes.

Comment: Ihr macht mich *nervös*

Comment: Das Kopfrechnen ist aber kein psychischer Prozess.

Comment: @userunknown natürlich ist es ein psychischer prozess. kognition ist teil der psyche

Answer (score 3):

Die Prozesse, die vom Gehirn gesteuert werden, werden in der Neurophysiologie gerne auch als [**Hirnfunktionen**](http://flexikon.doccheck.com/de/Gehirn) bezeichnet.

Man unterscheidet dabei *alle* Hirnfunktionen von den *höheren* Hirnfunktionen (wie z.B. Sprache, Gedächntis, kognitive Prozesse usw.).

Der [Hirntod](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirntod) wird definiert durch den Ausfall der (messbaren) Hirnfunktionen.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach bezeichnet "Hirnfunktionen" wie "Gehirnaktivität" und "Gehirntätigkeit" die mithilfe von Geräten messbare physiologische Aktivität des Gehirns und umfasst nicht die aus subjektiver Perspektive teilweise wahrnehmbaren Gedanken und Gefühle.

Comment: Doch schon. Das sind die sog. "höheren" Hirnfunktionen. Siehe auch http://hirnforschung.kyb.mpg.de/hirnforschung/forschung-am-lebenden-gehirn/was-sind-kognitive-prozesse.html

Comment: Auf der verlinkten Seite steht aber gerade: "Der Begriff ‘Hirnfunktion‘ ist üblicherweise sehr Organ-bezogen definiert". Wenn du schaust, was du findest, wenn du "Hirnfunktionen" googelts, dann kommen, soweit ich das sehe, überwiegend, wenn nicht ausschließlich, Seiten, die sich der Messung der Elektrizität, des Blutflusses usw. widmen. Z.B. sowas: http://physiologie.cc/XVI.9.htm Die "höheren Hirnfunktionen" sind somit eigentlich neurophysiologische Korrelate von Kognition, nicht aber die Kognition selbst. Bin aber für überzeugende Quellen offen.

Comment: @what: Willst Du mit 1) sagen, dass es subjektiv wahrnehmbare Gedanken/Gefühle gibt, die sich nicht messen lassen? Die sich prinzipiell nicht messen lassen, oder nicht so, dass jemand von außen den Inhalt des Gedankens exact ablesen kann? Hatten die ersten Leute, die über Hirntätigkeiten nachdachten auch schon entsprechende Geräte?

Comment: Die heutige Begriffstrennung rührt aus der Nichtmessbarkeit von Gedankeninhalten her. Niemand kann heute das Gedächtnis auslesen oder Gedanken messen. Vielleicht kann man das in der Zukunft einmal, denn natürlich sind die Gedanken Effekte der physiologischen Aktivität, aber so lange das unmöglich ist, gibt es eben zwei Disziplinen, die sich jeweils mit der Außen- und der Innensperspektive beschäftigen. Was früher einmal mit Hirntätigkeit gemeint war, ist mir egal. "Braun" bezeichnete auch einmal einen violetten Farbton und "Frau" war eine adelige Dame.